# What does global step mean?

Tags: google-cloud-ml, criteo

I recently completed the [Cloud ML Criteo tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/criteo_tft/README.md), and one of the final log messages from the distributed training job on the "small" dataset (~40M examples) was:

`Saving dict for global step 7520: accuracy = 0.78864, ...`

What does "global step" refer to here? I originally thought it was:

`global step = (number of training examples * number of epochs) / batch size`

However the training set size is 40.8M, the batch size is 30K, and the number of epochs is 5, so this doesn't lead to the right answer:

`(40.8M x 5) / 30K = 6800`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand this now. Even though the training set size is 40.8M examples, there is a [line](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/criteo_tft/trainer/task.py#L58) in the code that says it is 45M examples (I don't know why). And

(45M x 5) / 30K = 7500

which basically matches the log message.